# DIfference between Innodb and Myisam indecies?

Tags: mysql

what is the difference between Innodb indexes and Myisam indexes?Also can any one tell the order of multiple indexes.Which order should we use in multiple indecies?

Answer (score 0):

see for example [this Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_MySQL_database_engines) for a list of differences between myisam and innodb, e.g. table-level locking vs row-level locking.